# LINQ groupby and json output

Tags: c#, linq

my task is to group the data from a list of Subscription object which has the following structure:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public string ApplicationId { get; private set; }
    public string UserCode { get; private set; }
    public string SubscriptionId { get; private set; }
    public string SubscriptionCode { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; private set; }
}
```

The code return a list of subscription, so List. In my case I've several items with same ApplicationId but different StartDate and EndDate. Basically I have to group these items
in order to create a json structure like this:

```
"applicationId" : {
    "subscriptions" : [
        {
            "startdate"  : ...,
            "enddate"  : ...,
        },
        {
            "startdate"  : ...,
            "enddate"  : ...,
        },      
    ]
}
```

Can I achieve this using LINQ?

Comment: The group yes, the JSON no.

Comment: As it stands the answer to this question is "Yes". If you add a code example of your current attempt to group the items we can help you further.

Comment: I don't see what's so wrong with this question that it deserves so many close / down votes.

Comment: I was looking for an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
subscriptions.GroupBy(item => item.SubscriptionCode)
.Select(group => new { Subscription = group.Key, Items = group.Select(item => new { StartDate = item.StartDate, EndDate = item.EndDate}) })
```

Not sure if it will work but it reads like it will.

subscriptions is just a list of your object.